# AWS connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created 10 instances on AWS without key(?) and

I tried to connect to them via the web browser(crom).

I could connect to 2 instances but after that,

all my attempts are banned or connections timed out with the message like this

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

What's the problem?

Comment: It's not possible to create an instance without a key. Is your current IP address allowed to SSH by the instances' security groups?

Comment: Oh sure I can. I used <AMI ID : RStudio-0.98.1103_R-3.2.0_ubuntu-14.04-LTS-64bit (ami-a4cef3f6)> and I can get to it by public DNS. the security group is launch-wizard-2.

Comment: Some instances can be created without a key.  Those a few and far between.  It depends on the AMI.

Comment: If there was a service listening you'd get "connection refused".  Timeout indicates an issue wit hthe security group not allowing ssh access from your location.  You need to set it to allow TCP port 22 IN.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a .pem key that is created with the instance.    OR you can select an existing key to use.  I am confused how you were able to create the instances without a key.

Answer (score -1):

Click "Instances" on the right panel,
and right click one of instances,

Networking > Change Security Groups > and change it to laucnch-wizard-1